# pamie How to access variables in framset

Tags: python, html, frame, pamie, frameset-iframe

my issue is about accessing Frame that included into frameset
so it's like that

```
IFRAME 
 \
   FRAMESET
           \FRAMESET
                   \
                    FRAME
```

i've tried so hard to solve it , but i only could access to the iframe and it's automatically accessed to FRAMESET but still can't find a way to access the last frame !

so let's look into the pamie :

```
self.frameName = None               # The current frame name or index. Nested frames are
                                    # supported in the format frame1.frame2.frame3
```

i don't understand what the mean by saying `supported in the format` ..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ieobj.Document.Frames[framName].document.Frames[innerFrame]
```

Set value

```
ieobj.Document.Frames[framName].document.Frames[innerFrame].document.forms[myForm][textBox].value="someval"
```

Comment: so in case i want to set value to textBox in the innerframe , how is it possible ?  thanks

Comment: Actually, you should probably switch to something better than PAMIE for working with iframes, something like [Seleniumhq](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: mr.Patrick thank you very much your could works pretty good , i've insert the wrong name of frame